# git pull merge misunderstanding

Tags: git, git-merge

I have two branches in my local git repository, master and Logging.  Both branches have remotes on BitBucket.  master is the main branch of the project I'm currently working on.  When other developers have finished features, they merge their branches into master.  Logging is my current feature branch and was created from master.

To get the latest updates and reduce my merge pain, every so often I do a:

```
git pull origin master
```

while the Logging branch is checked out.  My understanding of this command is it fetches from the remote origin of the master branch and merges any changes into the local master.

I then do:

```
git merge master
```

What I'm intending to do here is merge the changes I've just pulled into the Logging branch.  However git always responds with:

```
Already up-to-date.
```

Indeed looking at git log and gitk seems to indicate that my local Logging branch does already contain the just pulled contents of master.  I wasn't expecting that doing a "git pull origin master" would affect my Logging branch at all.  What am I not understanding here?

Comment: you might have set up the Logging branch to track origin's master -- in that case, pulling will also merge that. Use `git branch -vv` to look at your branches; when there is something like `[origin/master]` (a remote branch name in square brackets) behind a branch, it's tracking that branch

Comment: Which branch was checked out when you started? It's rather _important_.

Comment: @JanHudec Ah, when I did the "git pull origin master" I was in the Logging branch.  I interpreted the "git pull origin master" as fetch and merge the remote of the master branch into the local master branch.  Does the "git pull origin master" pull from the origin of the currently checked out branch into the master branch?

Comment: @JanHudec Ah, I can see from your answer below that "git pull origin master" does neither of the above.

Comment: @JanHudec I've updated the question to provide correct checked out branch information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Git pull includes a merge:

```
git pull origin master
```

is equivalent to

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master
```

I.e. it *merges* the specified origin's branch into *currently checked out branch*.

The `git fetch origin` alone does not look at currently checked out branch at all. What it does is get the revisions and store the remote heads under `refs/remotes/origin` namespace. That's where the `git merge origin/master` pulls it from (if name is not qualified with `refs/something`, git looks in `refs/heads`, `refs/tags` and `refs/remotes`).

Comment: Ah, thanks for this.  So in this context, assuming that my Logging branch tracks the remote Logging branch, what does git fetch origin get exactly?  The origin of the currently checked out branch or the origin of master?

Comment: @GilesRoberts: The `fetch` does not look at current branch at all. It by default fetches all remote branches into the `refs/remotes/<remotename>` namespace.

Comment: now that explains why I've been scratching my head while performing some git operations.  Thanks a lot.